# value returned from a function is undefined javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i keep getting 'undefined' error whenever i get the value from a function, created by another function.

whenever `paste()` is executed, i want to get the value of the pasted text and display the text when `onclick()` is activated.

i get `undefined`  error during `onclick()` event. can someone look into it please.

```
$("input").on({
    'paste': function(e) {

    //get pasted text
    var text = somefunction(e);
    getval(text);
} });

function getval(text) {
    return text;
}

$(function() {
$(document).on('click','#submit', function () {
    text = getval();
    console.log(text);
} });
```

Comment: Have you heard of `return`?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining the function like this:

```
function getval(text) {
    return text;
}
```

but when you call it later, you don't pass any parameter to the function:

```
text = getval();
```

so it is not returning anything since `text` is not defined.

You could do:

```
$(function() {

$("input").on({
    'paste': function(e) {

    //get pasted text
    var text = somefunction(e);
} });


$(document).on('click','#submit', function () {
    console.log(text);
});
});
```

Comment: can you explain more, i dont understand. i know im missing something but i cant figure out.

Comment: so how do i pass the parameter? am i missing some syntax? what else do i need to add to pass the parameter?

Comment: for some reasons, i need the `function getval()`, as some functions will be using it too.

Comment: But `getval()` is just getting a variable as parameter and returning it again. So it is not really doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass text value in getval() function in the following place"Missing parameter here":

```
$(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '#submit', function () {
        text = getval("Missing parameter here");
        console.log(text);
    }
    });
```